# Don't nag me when I'm on the page of a question that I've answered which I've just migrated

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, vote-to-close, off-topic

On meta, when a question you've answered is migrated, you will receive a banner at the top of the screen:

[image: migrated answer notification banner]

However, if I am *on the page* and the person responsible for migrating the question because:

- I'm a moderator and I migrated it through the close dialog
- I am the last person to cast a vote which caused it to be migrated

And the page refreshes, *don't* nag me on the page refresh, as, well, it's obvious because *I've performed the action*:

[image: nag on question I've migrated]

It's easy enough to dismiss, but it's an unnecessary nag in this specific case.

Comment: Fair enough, but this sounds like a once-in-a-lifetime situation.

Comment: @balpha So that means if/when it happens again, you'll implement it?  **Deal.** It's only been four months and this has happened to me once.  I'm betting it will happen again.

Comment: Why so defensive? Where did I say it wouldn't be implemented?

Comment: @balpha You surprise me, and defy historical trends with this, thank you =)

Comment: It's always a question of "is it worth the effort". If this had been a half-day project, you'd have received a [status-declined] in no time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlikely situation, but adding that check was easy enough. The user casting the final close vote won't be notified of the migration anymore after the next build.